# log4j: Could not find resource

Tags: java, macos, logging, log4j

I have this `log4j.properties`

in this path:

```
❯ ls -l /Users/eladb/workspaceQa/MobileAutomationWebService/web-services/src/main/resources/log4j.properties                                                         [15:54:01]
-rw-r--r--  1 eladb  eng  853 Jun 27 15:41 /Users/eladb/workspaceQa/MobileAutomationWebService/web-services/src/main/resources/log4j.properties
```

however, when I run my application I see in the console:

```
log4j: Trying to find [/Users/eladb/workspaceQa/MobileAutomationWebService/web-services/src/main/resources/log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f.
log4j: Trying to find [/Users/eladb/workspaceQa/MobileAutomationWebService/web-services/src/main/resources/log4j.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [/Users/eladb/workspaceQa/MobileAutomationWebService/web-services/src/main/resources/log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().

log4j: Could not find resource: [/Users/eladb/workspaceQa/MobileAutomationWebService/web-services/src/main/resources/log4j.properties].
```

here is my code:

```
public class DeviceRepositoryFromJsonFile implements DeviceRepository {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DeviceRepositoryFromJsonFile.class);


    public DeviceRepositoryFromJsonFile() {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        filePath = Constants.devicesJsonPath;
        jsonFileHandlerDevice = new JsonFileHandler<>(filePath);
        devices = fetchFromFile();
    }
```

I'm using gradle

what am i missing?

Comment: Please provide more information about your application. Do you use Maven or  Gradle ? Otherwise how do you package your application ?

Comment: You can also try to pass in the properties file on the command line. `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///Users/eladb/workspaceQa/MobileAutomationWebService/web-services/src/main/resources/log4j.properties`

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this issue today myself.

All you need to do is use the `file://` protocol before putting the path of the properties file for log4j to read.

So, your path will something be like

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///Users/eladb/workspaceQa/MobileAutomationWebService/web-services/src/main/resources/log4j.properties
```

Hope it helps someone else by pointing them to the correct solution quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that server is not looking for that folder in the root server folder

Comment: what do you mean? i see it looks in there but find nothing

Comment: I refer that maybe your file path root is C:/.... and your server is looking for that file path in c:/serverRootFolder/.... in this case both path doesn`t match. I can`t tell you exactly because i don´t know anything about your file structure.

Comment: There is no C: in OSX ... AFAIK

Comment: just an example... the theory is the same